# It is not possible to find a positional parameter that accepts the 'kernel.bin'

Tags: powershell, cat

command:

```
cat bootsect.bin kernel.bin > os-image.bin
```

Error:

```
Get-Content : It is not possible to find a positional parameter that accepts the 'kernel.bin' argument.
No linha:1 caractere:1
+ cat bootsect.bin kernel.bin > os-image.bin
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

How do I solve this?

I'm on a win 10 64Bits computer, installed everything to get here and stopped this error that I don't know how to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that `Get-Content`, which is the cmdlet `cat` is an alias for, doesn't understand what it is asked to do.

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7) provides examples and syntax. Should you pass a single string, that is interpreted as a file name, as parameter position zero is same as `-path`. As there are no additional positioned parameters, the cmdlet doesn't understand what `kernel.bin` is supposed to be.

If you'd like to cat multiple files, pass file names as an array like so,

```
cat file1,file2 > otherfile
```

or use a variable

```
$myFiles = gci <somepath>
cat $myFiles > otherfile
```